# How to set levels based on data frame column

Tags: r

This is one of the dataframe examples in the last column which is my clust it contains the cluster info about the species to which it belongs.

```
hc$call$X
          Dim.1        Dim.2        Dim.3        Dim.4      clust
23  -2.77434470  0.458343668  0.332179098 -0.019648430 versicolor
14  -2.63310070 -0.961506729  0.180796084  0.019215534 versicolor
33  -2.61494794  1.793575856  0.047228419  0.229235932 versicolor
43  -2.55363840 -0.479100690  0.305766453  0.066601453 versicolor
38  -2.52733191  0.592292774  0.019435812  0.136504550 versicolor
34  -2.44617739  2.150727877 -0.082668045  0.048214393 versicolor
7   -2.44402884  0.047644198  0.335470401  0.036775557 versicolor
39  -2.42963258 -0.904180040  0.193254662  0.009738423 versicolor
48  -2.39437631 -0.386246873  0.139467905  0.048834762 versicolor
5   -2.38984217  0.646835383  0.015738196  0.035922813 versicolor
47  -2.38473317  1.120429702  0.057217858  0.152230967 versicolor
3   -2.36422905 -0.341908024  0.044201485 -0.028377053 versicolor
20  -2.34336905  1.127849382  0.132630467  0.037756420 versicolor
9   -2.33464048 -1.115327675  0.145076864  0.026859221 versicolor
12  -2.32613087  0.133078335  0.093759244  0.133483413 versicolor
4   -2.29938422 -0.597394508  0.091290106  0.065955560 versicolor
41  -2.28647514  0.441715388  0.034894909 -0.106983249 versicolor
30  -2.26526149 -0.337731904  0.068435776  0.108279885 versicolor
1   -2.26470281  0.480026597 -0.127706022 -0.024168204 versicolor
16  -2.26221453  2.686284485  0.030526609 -0.050533737 versicolor
8   -2.23284716  0.223148073 -0.088695498  0.024612096 versicolor
49  -2.22944655  0.997959764 -0.181492780  0.014928135 versicolor
25  -2.22716331  0.137254455  0.117993536  0.270140352 versicolor
13  -2.21845090 -0.728676165 -0.230911237 -0.002425038 versicolor
36  -2.20780890 -0.206107398 -0.225441580 -0.168907873 versicolor
17  -2.20758770  1.483609363 -0.005344094 -0.188817432 versicolor
22  -2.20701284  0.924121427  0.159865277 -0.059597330 versicolor
50  -2.20383344  0.009216358 -0.153029490 -0.049371732 versicolor
15  -2.19874060  1.860057113 -0.472900998 -0.194731769 versicolor
18  -2.19034951  0.488838316 -0.044215316 -0.093090438 versicolor
10  -2.18432817 -0.469013561 -0.253765567  0.039899288 versicolor
40  -2.16971071  0.268878961 -0.175883821 -0.007047406 versicolor
28  -2.16857717  0.527149525 -0.206816248 -0.010275393 versicolor
11  -2.16631010  1.043690653 -0.268681102 -0.016731367 versicolor
31  -2.14012214 -0.504540690 -0.075008442  0.048188868 versicolor
29  -2.13956345  0.313217810 -0.271150240 -0.084259221 versicolor
45  -2.13705901  1.142229262  0.248433561  0.151043437 versicolor
35  -2.10997488 -0.460201841 -0.170274861 -0.029022947 versicolor
2   -2.08096115 -0.674133557 -0.234608854 -0.103006775 versicolor
6   -2.07563095  1.489177523  0.026968294 -0.006608180 versicolor
46  -2.06974430 -0.711052725 -0.063929826 -0.140269507 versicolor
27  -2.05115137  0.242163553  0.086364011 -0.067680060 versicolor
37  -2.04514621  0.661558111 -0.484537410 -0.196358525 versicolor
44  -1.96444768  0.472326668  0.309601318 -0.177093014 versicolor
26  -1.95184633 -0.625618588 -0.305640982 -0.043561651 versicolor
21  -1.91432300  0.408855708 -0.421292594 -0.010921286 versicolor
19  -1.89857200  1.405018794 -0.374343275 -0.061095967 versicolor
42  -1.85812246 -2.337415158 -0.204234223 -0.289863919 versicolor
32  -1.83159477  0.423695068 -0.270467377 -0.239870381 versicolor
24  -1.81866953  0.085558526  0.034488596 -0.151140999 versicolor
58  -0.48732274 -1.852429087  0.249265266  0.040520205     setosa
99  -0.44766702 -1.543792034  0.190400930 -0.199946457     setosa
94  -0.36218338 -2.019237873  0.105821048 -0.019570812     setosa
61  -0.11019628 -2.654072819 -0.046790444 -0.013760731     setosa
80  -0.04025861 -1.058718547 -0.319573330 -0.064788156     setosa
65  -0.03335470 -0.439003210  0.194932893 -0.109048499     setosa
60   0.01142619 -1.034018275  0.538899390  0.028461184     setosa
82   0.02345269 -1.572475594 -0.241552281  0.032772444     setosa
89   0.06958832 -0.219503335  0.291579274  0.147144581     setosa
96   0.09136066 -0.181192126  0.128978343  0.229959626     setosa
81   0.13079518 -1.562271834 -0.149983478  0.009402523     setosa
68   0.15881005 -0.792095742 -0.302037174  0.205297735     setosa
70   0.16491790 -1.302609230 -0.172837808  0.051726849     setosa
85   0.22397877 -0.287773512  0.665249720  0.254828368     setosa
97   0.22771687 -0.384920081  0.156213154  0.132605877     setosa
83   0.24153827 -0.777256383 -0.151211957 -0.023651360     setosa
100  0.25673059 -0.598851796  0.091879161  0.058622049     setosa
91   0.27907778 -1.120028524  0.094487601  0.270657196     setosa
90   0.28347724 -1.329324639  0.089410023 -0.008905805     setosa
95   0.28858624 -0.855730320  0.130889685  0.107402349     setosa
93   0.33653037 -0.988404018 -0.199389755 -0.006530562     setosa
67   0.35025167 -0.196311735  0.490873075  0.191509364     setosa
107  0.36701769 -1.561502891  0.986893267  0.133123834     setosa
56   0.38868734 -0.593283636  0.124191550  0.240831300     setosa
54   0.40748306 -1.754403989 -0.023101768 -0.065768835     setosa
86   0.42913912  0.845582241  0.450634071  0.109675181  virginica
62   0.44069345 -0.063295188  0.205073815 -0.040126082     setosa
72   0.47628719 -0.417320281 -0.264952227 -0.113568273     setosa
63   0.56210831 -1.764724381 -0.765771394 -0.045731157     setosa
98   0.57638829 -0.154873597 -0.271650362  0.019860679     setosa
92   0.62456979  0.024923029 -0.020481147  0.147686401     setosa
74   0.63285820 -0.416387721 -0.291896252  0.274220152     setosa
79   0.66480037 -0.225927855  0.085863889  0.036439840     setosa
75   0.70266118 -0.063411820 -0.446027008 -0.043458325     setosa
64   0.71956189 -0.186224606 -0.068658945  0.164807198     setosa
52   0.73133743  0.594614726 -0.094121716 -0.004903623  virginica
71   0.73768265  0.396571562  0.616526306  0.083284123  virginica
57   0.74652974  0.773019312  0.148969403  0.077369785  virginica
76   0.87427365  0.250793393 -0.472578954 -0.101715736  virginica
66   0.87540719  0.509063957 -0.503511382 -0.104943723  virginica
139  0.92482492  0.017223100  0.416826193 -0.005238409     setosa
59   0.92790164  0.032226078 -0.596169361  0.029879609     setosa
150  0.96065603 -0.024331668  0.528248807  0.163078032     setosa
122  0.97798073 -0.571764325  0.828127201 -0.027755587     setosa
128  1.02095055  0.064346029  0.337715967  0.008654401  virginica
88   1.04453138 -1.382988719 -0.688295960 -0.136835600     setosa
87   1.04872805  0.522051797 -0.395786384 -0.037209019  virginica
84   1.06109461 -0.633843245  0.105311387  0.183968453     setosa
55   1.07547470 -0.208421046 -0.398255523 -0.104736873     setosa
51   1.10178118  0.862972418 -0.684586163 -0.034833776  virginica
134  1.11414774 -0.292922623 -0.183488392  0.186343697     setosa
102  1.15788161 -0.698869862  0.530160149  0.040520754     setosa
143  1.15788161 -0.698869862  0.530160149  0.040520754     setosa
127  1.17510363 -0.316394472  0.129937757 -0.125420444     setosa
135  1.20247330 -0.811315271 -0.164723757  0.489483470     setosa
69   1.22509363 -1.622243803 -0.482304024 -0.225899769     setosa
73   1.23417810 -0.933325729 -0.368412272  0.009944526     setosa
53   1.24097932  0.616297654 -0.554006835 -0.009423397  virginica
77   1.25650912 -0.077256020 -0.727155002 -0.039688518  virginica
114  1.26011510 -1.162260421  0.580249290 -0.099157321     setosa
120  1.26376667 -1.706745380 -0.267536893  0.065180800     setosa
124  1.33323218 -0.481811219 -0.005428364 -0.139959148     setosa
138  1.34629210  0.422430611  0.180875478  0.215421288  virginica
78   1.35840512  0.331311682 -0.260826577 -0.066828064  virginica
111  1.36417549  0.692756454  0.284612074 -0.107860420  virginica
149  1.37278779  1.011254419  0.933395241 -0.026128648  virginica
104  1.44015066 -0.046987588  0.163630107  0.235770073  virginica
115  1.46764520 -0.442271587  1.003869574 -0.275658903     setosa
117  1.47143146  0.255621824  0.037431260  0.155330271  virginica
148  1.52117050  0.269069144  0.180178380 -0.119171137  virginica
147  1.56458048 -0.896686809 -0.026371352 -0.220192100     setosa
137  1.57625591  1.068581107  0.945853819 -0.035605759  virginica
116  1.59007732  0.676244806  0.638428708 -0.191862996  virginica
112  1.60267867 -0.421700450  0.023186408 -0.058331633  virginica
125  1.70073390  1.013921867  0.298450613  0.061643734  virginica
129  1.78834992 -0.187361215  0.270658006 -0.031087648  virginica
101  1.84456887  0.870421312  1.005401018  0.049249743  virginica
140  1.85204505  0.676128174 -0.012672115 -0.195195239  virginica
133  1.86270322 -0.178549495  0.354148712 -0.100009882  virginica
130  1.86364755  0.562290726 -0.715634119  0.208215164  virginica
105  1.86781222  0.295044824  0.395628375  0.016298272  virginica
146  1.87050329  0.386966082  0.256273852 -0.389256845  virginica
113  1.88390070  0.419249651  0.026338410 -0.146414939  virginica
142  1.90178409  0.689575494  0.130075005 -0.469696647  virginica
126  1.95432671  1.007777596 -0.419984722  0.218338351  virginica
145  1.99814710  1.049168747  0.632413436 -0.214045204  virginica
109  2.00668647 -0.711438654 -0.393990571  0.086510630  virginica
141  2.01481043  0.613885637  0.428332842 -0.247538313  virginica
121  2.03771630  0.910467410  0.234799484 -0.167951254  virginica
144  2.04055823  0.867520601  0.338144000 -0.045187126  virginica
103  2.20526679  0.562010477 -0.202914170 -0.059184194  virginica
110  2.25977735  1.921010376  0.397551897 -0.104838918  virginica
108  2.30243944  0.420065580 -0.651706439  0.238041242  virginica
132  2.30492772  2.626323468 -0.493473808  0.211675709  virginica
118  2.42632899  2.556661251 -0.127881459  0.273807183  virginica
131  2.43595373  0.259284433 -0.727816146  0.017923365  virginica
106  2.75187334  0.800409201 -0.582309103  0.101384486  virginica
136  2.79877045  0.856803329 -0.542906499 -0.295881050  virginica
123  2.89765149  0.413641060 -0.857421825  0.127336502  virginica
119  3.31069558  0.017780949 -0.703305304 -0.045188606  virginica
```

The `level` here trying to set is like this based on one of the stack answer:

```
levels(hc$call$X$clust) <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
```

My question is in the last column how this code `levels(hc$call$X$clust)` does it match the correct order of the clust since

As when I run this

```
levels(hc$call$X$clust)
[1] "setosa"     "versicolor" "virginica"
```

How do I make know if it is matching the `clust` order?

Any suggestion would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try `hc$call$X$clust <- factor(hc$call$X$clust, levels = unique(hc$call$X$clust))`

Comment: The order of arguments passed to `\`levels<-\`` is what you give it. If you call `factor(..)` _without_ `levels=`, then it defaults to the lexicographic sorting order of the unique values, which is often sufficient but not always. An example of when it is not: `ggplot2` honors factors when ordering categorical variables, so changing the order with `levels=c(...)` or `levels(myfactor) <- c(...)` is useful. In this case, since I'm inferring you are sourcing this on `iris`, it might be good to use the levels from the preexisting frame, perhaps `levels(hc$call$X$clust) <- levels(iris$Species)`.